# how to implement random.nextDouble of c# in c language

Tags: c

I want to generate a random double number between 0 and 1 in C. I used the following code 
to generate it, but still I'm getting p's value as 0.0000? Can anyone help me out in this?

```
double p;
int max;
int min;
max=1;
min=0;

p=  (double)(rand() % (max - min + 1) + min);
```

Comment: This can't work, because you are computing `rand () % 1` which is always 0, since every integer is a multiple of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
p = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
```

Comment: or `rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)` if you want to exclude 1 itself.

Comment: @tina, what is the result you are getting? I did a quick test here and it certainly works for me. Keep in mind that the cast to 'double' is important.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `drand48`; for your information the latest C++11 standard has a powerful standard random library.

If you don't want to use `drand48`, you might code something like e.g. `((double) (rand() % 10000000)) * 1.0e-6` but I don't recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

something like a Tausworthe-based PRNG would work well, [LuaJIT2](http://luajit.org/download.html) (beta) has a very nice variant that correctly scales between [n..m] and [0..1], you can find it in the lib_math.c file in LuaJIT's source.

You can also have a look at the the RNG's use by R [here](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/RNG.c).